# Mouse Precision Algorithm Have A Gap On Different Screens For Remote Desktop App Made Made By Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, webrtc, remote-desktop

Hey I Made My Electron Js Application Its A Combination Of WebRTC Socket IO For Reciver App ( This App Installed on remote pc it send back video stream) Sender APP ( This App also made in electron js but uses react js framework )

So Sender App record mouse moment on video source of reciver app so it look like we are hovering on screeen issue is that i am facing gap from my mouse and remote pc mouse means its not precise

```
type here
```

I found many algorith nothing helps here my github repo for sender [Github Repo for reciver app for remote screen](https://github.com/stormappears/electronRDP)

here is repo for sender which can send remote cordinates [repo of sender](https://github.com/stormappears/electonwebrtchost/tree/master)

Here is litttle explaination

Sender App Code ( Electron , react )

```
  //Mouse ClickL Event
  const handleMouseClick = ({
    clientX,
    clientY,
  }) =>{
    //scr element
// const screlement = document.getElementById('remscreen');
// const clientWidth = screlement.offsetWidth;
// const clientHeight = screlement.offsetHeight;

      socket.emit("mouseclickl" , {
        clientX,
        clientY,
        // clientWidth,
        // clientHeight,
        clientWidth: window.innerWidth,
        clientHeight: window.innerHeight,
        room,
      })
  }
```

```
  return (
    <>
      <div id="bg" onMouseLeave={() => {}}>
        <div
          className="controlpin"
          id="controlpin"
          ref={controllerPinRef}
          onClick={() => {
            controllerPanel.current.style.visibility = "visible";
            controllerPinRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
            controllerPanel.current.style.zIndex = "10";
            controllerPinRef.current.style.zIndex = "8";
          }}
        >
          {" "}
        </div>

        <div
          className="controller"
          id="controller"
          ref={controllerPanel}
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            setIsMouseOnPanel(true);
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {}}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            id="roomInput"
            ref={inputRoom}
            onChange={handleRoomInputChange}
          />
          <button onClick={joinRoom} id="connect_user">
            Connect User{" "}
          </button>
          {/* <input type="text" id='input' ref={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>{ setMessage(e.target.value)}} placeholder='enter message ' /> */}
          {/* <button onClick={sendMessage} >Send Message</button> */}
          <div className="samplethressdiv">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="samplethres"
              onChange={handlesamplethress}
              placeholder="sampling thresold"
            />
            <label htmlFor="samplethres">Sampling Thresold</label>
          </div>
          <div className="disablemousecdiv">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="myCheckbox"
              label="Disable Client Mouse"
              checked={isMouseHide}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="myCheckbox">Disable Client Mouse</label>
          </div>
          <div className="changeCtrlPos">
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                document.getElementById("controlpin").style.cssText =
                  "right: 1200px";
              }}
            >
              Left
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                document.getElementById("controlpin").style.cssText =
                  "left: 1200px";
              }}
            >
              Right
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="toggerdiv">
            <button
              className="toggerdiv_button"
              onClick={() => {
                if (enableToggler == false) {
                  setEnableToggler(true);
                } else {
                  setEnableToggler(false);
                }
              }}
            >
              Mouse Toggler
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={getImage}>Capture Screenshot</button>
          </div>
          <button
            className="closepenlbtn"
            onClick={() => {
              controllerPanel.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
              controllerPinRef.current.style.visibility = "visible";
            }}
          >
            {" "}
            close panel
          </button>
        </div>

        <div
          className="remscreendiv"
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
          onClick={handleMouseClick}
          onContextMenu={(event) => {
            if (event.button === 2) {
              event.preventDefault();
              socket.emit("mouseclickr", { room });
              console.log("You right-clicked on the element!");
            }
          }}
        >
          <video id="remscreen" ref={remoteVideoRef} />
        </div>

        <video id="myscreen" ref={currentUserVideoRef} />
        <img src={image} alt="screenshot" />
        <h1> Width : {clientWidth}</h1>
        <h1> Height : {clientHeight}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

Here Is Receiver

```
// //mouse codinates
socket.on("mouse_cord", (data) => {
  const { screen } = require("electron");
  // const primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
  // const { width, height } = primaryDisplay.workAreaSize;

     const primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
     const screenWidth = primaryDisplay.bounds.width;
     const screenHeight = primaryDisplay.bounds.height;

  // Calculate scaling factors
  const ratioX = screenWidth / data.clientWidth;
  const ratioY = screenHeight / data.clientHeight;
  const scaledX = data.clientX * ratioX;
  const scaledY = data.clientY * ratioY;

  keepMouseOut(data.isMouseHide);

  //  console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
  console.log("Hey its client width " + data.clientWidth);
  console.log("Hey its client height " + data.clientHeight);

  // robot.moveMouse(hostX, hostY);
  // console.log(`Current screen width: ${width}`);
  // console.log(`Current screen height: ${height}`);

  // mouse cord active handelling mode
  if (data.enableToggler == true) {
  const { screen } = require("electron");
  // const primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
  // const { width, height } = primaryDisplay.workAreaSize;

  const primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
  const screenWidth = primaryDisplay.bounds.width;
  const screenHeight = primaryDisplay.bounds.height;

    // Calculate scaling factors
    const ratioX = screenWidth / data.clientWidth;
    const ratioY = screenHeight / data.clientHeight;
    const scaledX = data.clientX * ratioX;
    const scaledY = data.clientY * ratioY;

  console.log("Mouse Cord Data Starts Here")
  console.log("===============================================================")
  console.log("Client Width : " +  data.clientWidth);
  console.log("Client Height : " + data.clientHeight);
  console.log("");
  console.log("============== Client ScreenData ==================");
  console.log("Screen Width : " + screenWidth );
  console.log("Screen Height : " +  screenHeight)
console.log("");
console.log("============== Scaled Count ==================");
console.log("scaled count X :" + scaledX);
console.log("scaled count Y :" + scaledY);



    robot.setMouseDelay(0);
    robot.moveMouse(scaledX, scaledY);
    var mouse = robot.getMousePos();
    robot.moveMouseSmooth(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    console.log("system mouse x" + mouse.x);
    console.log("system mouse y" + mouse.y);
  } else {
    console.log(data.enableToggler + " : toggler ");
  }
});
```

I know code can bad practise , but issue is relevant

First Of All I Am Making Remote Desktop Connection From Those Apps  I Have
Application Which Launched On Pc I Want To Control And In Problem Statement I call it reciver because it recives mouse cordinates from sender app

Now Sender Send Mouse Cordinates Captured On Div In React Js It send I Used Common Foud Algorith for pointer alignment for both screen

Issue Is : My Algorith Is Not Working Welll There Gap Between Reciver Device And Sender (controller ) help me fix that

Keep In Mind Both Apps Are Electron Forge , React JS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First Of All I Am Making Remote Desktop Connection From Those Apps  I Have
Application Which Launched On Pc I Want To Control And In Problem Statement I call it reciver because it recives mouse cordinates from sender app 

Now Sender Send Mouse Cordinates Captured On Div In React Js It send I Used Common Foud Algorith for pointer alignment for both screen

Issue Is : My Algorith Is Not Working Welll There Gap Between Reciver Device And Sender (controller ) help me fix that

Keep In Mind Both Apps Are Electron Forge , React JS